# Can't extract tar.gz file from Apache

Tags: gzip

I'm trying to do install manifoldcf on Ubuntu.

I downloaded the file - apache-manifoldcf-1.9-src.tar.gz - directly
from Apache (and I've tried different version as well with the same results).

Using tar xvf, tar zxvf, and tried both with -zxvf, and I get the error:

```
gzip:stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I also tried to just unzip using gunzip filename.tar.gz and it returned:

```
gzip: apache-manifoldcf-1.9-src.tar.gz: not in gzip format
```

It seems unlikely that everything I downloaded from that page - manifoldcf.apache.org - is broken…so it must be me!

Help?

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: Could you run `file apache-manifoldcf-1.9-src.tar.gz` and give the results?

Comment: Here are the results:     apache-manifoldcf-1.9-src.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines

Comment: How did you download that? You likely downloaded a page that itself contains a link to the file, or an error page. You should be able to open it in a browser to see what it is.

Comment: I see that now…thanks….I clicked on the link for the download, copied it, then did a wget and pasted the link. Let me get back to that page and check it out…thanks!

Comment: That was it! The link I was copying was a link to the page with the mirrors….Thank you!

Comment: Ok…another question - I don't know how to select your comment as an answer…lo

Comment: You can't mark a comment as the accepted answer so I posted it as an answer. I would also remove the [tag:apache] tag, as it indicates the question is linked to the Apache HTTP server, and not the Apache Foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `gunzip` says the file isn't in gzip format, it's a good idea to check what it's being detected as. `file apache-manifoldcf-1.9-src.tar.gz` gives you the detected filetype based on the file's contents, and not on its extension.

In this case, it indicates `HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines`, indicating it's actually likely to be an HTML file, for which a more proper extension would be `.htm` or `.html`. This generally occurs when downloading something through `wget`, and the downloaded file is a redirect page or an error page.

In the OP's case, this was a page offering a list of mirrors and not the actual file.